# How to match a string and ignore the extension if present?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex that picks a users username something like `dave.me` but excludes an extension if present.

Expected behavior

```
dave.me # Would pick dave.me
dave.me.json # Would pick dave.me only
dave_me@me # Would pick dave_me@me
dave_me@me.json # Would pick dave_me@me
dave_me@me.com.json # Would pick dave_me@me.com only
dave_me@me.com # Would pick dave_me@me.com
```

So far, I have this:

```
[\w.@+-]+(?=.json|.csv|.xml)
```

..but this fails in strings such as `dave.me` and passes only if the string contains either `.json` `.csv` or `.xml`.

Comment: Do you only want this for specific extensions (`.json`, `.csv` & `.xml`) only, or are there other extensions?

Comment: @Ambro-r yes, I want those specific extensions only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^[\w.@+-]+?(?=\.json|\.csv|\.xml|\s|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLPip1/2).

### Changes that were made to your pattern:

- Added `^` to only match usernames at the beginning of the string. Otherwise, any other word will be matched.
- Used a lazy matching `+?` to prevent capturing the extensions as well.
- Escaped the unescaped `.` characters (i.e., `\.`).
- Added `|\s|$` to the Lookahead so that the capturing stops if followed by either an extension or a whitespace character, or if it's at the end of the string.

Comment: This works only if there is a white space at the end ? In the use case i'll be using the regex in more than likely the white space will not be present

Comment: @DRaymond Check the updated answer and explanation.